# maven cyclic dependencies

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, jboss

I have a modular maven project, in which two modules, "BIZ" and "EJB" contain somthing like this:

```
//PART OF "BIZ" Module:

public interface MyInterface{

 public void foo();

}
............................................
public class ImplFactory{

public static MyInterface getInterfaceImplementation(){
MyInterface ret=null;
Class<? extends MyInterface> cl = null;
                try {
                    cl= (Class<? extends MyInterface>) Class.forName("InterfaceImpl");
                    ret= cl.newInstance();
                    }
                ....
                ret ret;
}
.......................................
public class MyClassX{

    public static void doSomethingX(){

    }
}

//PART OF "EJB" Module:

public class InterfaceImpl implements MyInterface
@EJB
private MyEJB1 ejb1;

public void  foo(){
    ejb1.doSomething();
}
........................................
@Stateless
public class MyEJB1{

    public void doSomething(){
    ...
    MyClassX.doSomethingX();
    ....
    }

}
```

As you see, **"EJB" depends on "BIZ"** as it uses *MyClassX* (in the truth, it uses several classes of BIZ). This is the reason why *ImplFactory* uses reflection to instantiate *InterfaceImpl*. The problem is *cl.newInstance()* will throw a **ClassCastException** as the 2 modules belong respectively to a WAR and a JAR (module "EJB" is compiled specifying type="ejb" and using the maven ejb plugin) and use different ClassLoaders (it runs on JBoss 7). On the other hand, *InterfaceImpl* cannot be moved to BIZ as it needs *MyEJB1* for its job and this would introduce a cyclic dependency.

So my question is: how would you solve this tricky situation (either programmatically or by changing the configuration)? 
I hope you can help me! Thanks!

Comment: FIrst question: Why not using (C)DI instead of factories?

Comment: At the moment I would keep the things as they are: I oversemplified the situation, but I am dealing with dozens of classes using getInterfaceImplementation().. (That is, I will consider it in a second moment).

Comment: I am now curious.. :) How would CDI help solving the problem described..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should split these dependencies a little bit more.

Something like this would be better:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── my-api ("API")
|   ├── pom.xml
|   └── src
|       └── main
|           └── java
|               └── my
|                   └── package
|                       └── MyInterface.java
├── my-ejb ("EJB")
|   ├── pom.xml
|   └── src
|       └── main
|           └── java
|               └── my
|                   └── package
|                       └── InterfaceImpl.java
└── my-web ("BIZ")
    ├── pom.xml
    └── src
        └── main
            ├── java
            |   └── my
            |       └── package
            |           └── ImplFactory.java
            └── webapp
                └── WEB-INF
                    └── web.xml
```

`BIZ` would depend on `EJB` that depends on `API`.

Now this will solve your immediate problem but I would not recommend you to create those factories, you should use [CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhb.html) instead but that's is a different story.

Comment: hi! Thanks for your answer! The problem is that unfortunately EJB depends on BIZ..

Comment: @Federico That's what you have to split up. Or move around.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can help but just sharing a few things which I have used.

1. For cyclic dependency one thing that I did when my war file had a src module in it. The referring module can just take the jar from the war by adding maven dep something as: (right now not sure about the exact syntax)
   `<dependancy> <groupid ../> <artifactid .war module name./> <jarModuleName> </dependancy>`
2. In one case I could not call the src of the war module because of self redundancy. Then I had to make a separate src module and add it as a dependency to all the war modules where it was required.

I am not sure if this can help you. Just wanted to share what I knew. Let me know if you can improve on my comments.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering, but honestly I didn't understand what you wanted to say.. :(

Comment: i'll try to share some code and explain more on my case in a day or two..thanks for your patience..